# Redirect from Falcon when called from Angular $http doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, falconframework

I have a Falcon app, and in the middleware I want to redirect using `falcon.HTTPMovedPermanently`. If a request comes in from a browser to a Falcon endpoint it works fine. But if the request comes in from Angular via $http the redirect never happens.

Let me try and explain the flow of this crazy app that was dropped in my lap:

- the initial request is made from a browser to
  foo.bar.com:8000/xxx/1234
- that routes to Angular, which sends a request using $http to foo.bar.com:8001/xxxx/1234/yyyy
- that routes to a falcon endpoint yyyy
- my middleware gets it first and redirects to foo.bar.com:8004/someotherthing
- but someotherthing is never hit
- the falcon endpoint runs and what Angular says is:

  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://foo.bar.com:8001/xxxx/1234/yyyy. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://foo.bar.com:8000' is therefore not allowed access.

Anyone know how I can get the redirect to work when called from Angular?

Comment: It's not angular telling you that...it's the browser itself. Would work fine if page was on same domain/port but since it's not you are subject to CORS restrictions. Get rid of the redirect if server and page will always be cross domain

Comment: Turns out this had nothing to do with the redirection I was trying to add. I removed that and still got the same thing. Then I found that the host was recently put behind a firewall and that is when this problem started. I am trying to resolve it with `falcon-cors`. Using that I no longer get the error from the browser, but now the falcon app says `Aborting response due to origin not allowed` Anyone have any experience with `falcon-cors`?

Comment: So after more debugging I've come to realization that my issue has nothing at all to do with the firewall or CORS. It's what I said in the first place: If a request comes in from a browser to a Falcon endpoint the redirect works fine. But if the request comes in from Angular via $http the redirect never happens.What could cause that? How can I track down and fix this?

Comment: But it is CORS related. Cross domain requests must fulfill an OPTIONS request and that can't have redirect.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I came to that realization after I posted. I think I should be able to set the proper CORS headers to allow it, but I have not figured out how do that. I know what they are and I can set them for a cross domain request abut not for a redirect.

Comment: So I was setting the header in the middleware, but I was raising the redirect again in the exception handler, so I tried setting the headers there and now I get a somewhat different message:
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://foo.bar.com:8004/falcon_passthrough/http://foo.bar.com/abc/123/xyz. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`
So that is some progress but not sure where to go from here. I am setting the header to `'*'`

Comment: Numerous headers involved and recommended not to use `*` and use actual referrer

Comment: Yes but when it says the origin is null what  will that match?

Comment: Should be able to detect origin. Is in `$_SERVER`

Comment: I don't have any control of what it detects.

Comment: I've created a new question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484478/cors-issue-when-trying-to-follow-redirect-in-angular` as it's become something very different from what this is about. Please look at that and offer any help you can. Thanks!